# Software for calculating long-term spectral averages

Tags: analysis, soundscape, software, ltsa

What software programs exist that can be used to calculate sound levels for long-durations of continuous audio files?

A helpful list of other sound processing programs was shared recently: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/a/136/112, but only [Triton](https://github.com/MarineBioAcousticsRC/Triton) is listed for calculating long-term spectral averages. [MANTA](https://bitbucket.org/CLO-BRP/manta-wiki/wiki/Home) is a similar tool for processing lots of continuous data.

I am interested in both stand-alone and/or programs that need to be run through Matlab/R/etc, but it's important for me to be able to export the LTSA product as an array or similar for further processing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

The free and open source software, **[PAMGuard](https://www.pamguard.org/)**, has an option for an LTSA module to be run while you're processing your acoustic data. This is stored in binary files which can be accessed using either:

- R (via the Pamguard R library, **[PamBinaries](https://github.com/TaikiSan21/PamBinaries)** by Taiki San), or
- Matlab (via the PAMGuard Matlab library, **[pgmatlab](https://github.com/PAMGuard/PAMGuardMatlab)**).

Once in either of these suites, you can handle the data and plot as you wish.

Comment: There is a similar answer in Stack Overflow with a little more detail here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231827/does-anyone-know-how-to-plot-long-term-spectral-averages-ltsa-and-psd-in-r/72129233#72129233

Answer (score 15):

I have been using this [code](https://github.com/tryan/LTSA/blob/master/python/ltsa.py) posted in Github from [tryan](https://github.com/tryan), which is written in Python, to build some LTSAs. It is basically Triton's algorithm but in Python. Since it is an open source code you can maybe change the algorithm to output the product you want. I was wondering if it would not be useful for you, since the resulting output of the LTSA is an image, converting the LTSA images into numpy arrays in Python. It might be a very naive step but depending on what you need it could be useful.

This repository also has the the relevant Matlab/Octave code.

Comment: Great to share your own code! Super helpful.

If you wouldn't mind, could you add that it is a github link that you are sharing, and your github username so folks could find it again if the link breaks?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am a new stack user and still learning how it works. I just edited the answer so the information is more clear now and with the github source.

Answer (score 7):

DetEdit has functionality to calculate LTSAs; it's a GUI but the code is written in MATLAB (open-source, relies on mkLtsa function mostly).

Article describing it: https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1007598

Code/instructions/wiki: https://github.com/MarineBioAcousticsRC/DetEdit

Answer (score 6):

I have not personally used the below linked code, but I did have this starred in my GitHub folder a while back and had been meaning to try it. It may provide the type of output you can work with more easily, compared to Triton.

https://github.com/schonkopf/long-term-spectrogram