# How to apply calibration infromation to Triton generated LTSAs

Tags: calibration, triton

Is it possible to apply single end-to-end calibration values or a transfer function to LTSA plots generated in Triton? The User Guide says that transfer functions are not applied to LTSAs but that a Remora could be built for this. I am fairly new to using Triton and was just wondering whether this is something that already exists?

Comment: My immediate response is that no it doesn't already exist, and if it does it probably is semi-specific for .x.wavs (the file type Triton was originally developed with) but I have created external LTSA code that is based on how LTSA's are generated in Triton that does allow to adjust for end-to-end calibration. I haven't touched it in a while and so it isn't very widely applicable but I will be working on it in the near future!

Comment: These two questions/answers might be helpful if you are open to other programs: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/306/software-for-calculating-long-term-spectral-averages/694#694
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231827/does-anyone-know-how-to-plot-long-term-spectral-averages-ltsa-and-psd-in-r/72129233#72129233

Comment: Thanks both comments are very useful. I know how to create the plots with PAMGuard and it does what I need, but I just wanted to compare the output of the two and compare run times, as I have to create quite a few of these. Many thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: Do you have an end to end calibration value? Are the triton values calibrated or just loaded from wav files?

Comment: yes, I have end to end calibration values. The Triton values are loaded from the wav files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/451)