# Does anyone have exhaustive list of courses related to bioacoustics all over the world

Tags: career

I'm a physics graduate and have completed Master's in Environment Management. I did a small project on the Comparative acoustics of two barbet species. I want to pursue bioacoustics as a career. Please provide a list of courses related to bioacoustics

Comment: Hi Vaibhav and welcome! It seems there is already a post about the same subject here  ["Holistic intro to bioacoustics for newbies"](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/121/holistic-intro-to-bioacoustics-for-newbies)

Answer (score 1):

A related Bioacoustics stack exchange post answers this question already:

See: "[Holistic intro to bioacoustics for newbies](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/121/holistic-intro-to-bioacoustics-for-newbies)"