# Are you a grad student working in Bioacoustics?

Tags: graduate-school

Applications now being accepted for the Graduate Summer Course in Bioacoustics, hosted again at The University of Southern Denmark. Many of the founders and members of this stack exchange have been students or teachers on this course, so you may ask around here whether former participants found it worthwhile. I myself also took the course back when I was a PhD student and now (many years later) I am part of the teaching team, so I can confirm I found it not only useful in learning bioacoustics theory and practical techniques, but also in forming a network of like-minded colleagues and friends.

This is a hands-on course focusing on methods for studying animal acoustic communication in air, water, and solids. Our amazing team of world-renowned experts will teach you the fundamentals of acoustics, signal analysis, psychoacoustics, animal sound production, perception and noise. In- and outdoor labs provide hands-on experience on sound and vibration recording, sound analysis, and playback in air and water with emphasis on methodological limitations and pitfalls.

Teachers: Iris Adam (SDU, DK), Jakob Christensen-Dalsgaard (SDU), Coen P.H. Elemans (SDU), Hannah ter Hofstede (Darthmouth, USA), Lasse Jakobsen (SDU), Mark Johnson (Aarhus University, DK), Elodie Mande-Briefer (Copenhagen University, DK), Natasha Mhatre (University of Western Ontario, CN), Ole Næsbye Larsen (SDU), Peter Teglberg Madsen (Aarhus University, DK), Nicolas Mathevon (ENES, FR), Jeppe Have Rasmussen (Copenhagen University, DK), Jakob Tougaard (Aarhus University, DK), Magnus Wahlberg (SDU), Sue Anne Zollinger (Manchester Metropolitan University, UK).

The course is taught at the marine and terrestrial field stations of the Department of Biology, University of Southern Denmark.

Application should be emailed to bioacoustics@biology.sdu.dk

Application deadline: April 1st, 2024.  Priority is given to students enrolled in a PhD-program at their home universities. Maximal number of participants:  24. Successful applicants will be notified of acceptance before May 1st, 2024.

More information and application requirements: [Graduate Summer Course in Bioacoustic SDU](https://studying%20animal%20acoustic%20communication%20in%20air,%20water,%20and%20solids.%20Our%20amazing%20team%20of%20world-renowned%20experts%20will%20teach%20you%20the%20fundamentals%20of%20acoustics,%20signal%20analysis,%20psychoacoustics,%20animal%20sound%20production,%20perception%20and%20noise.%20In-%20and%20outdoor%20labs%20provide%20hands-on%20experience%20on%20sound%20and%20vibration%20recording,%20sound%20analysis,%20and%20playback%20in%20air%20and%20water%20with%20emphasis%20on%20methodological%20limitations%20and%20pitfalls.%20%20%20Teachers:%20Iris%20Adam%20(SDU,%20DK),%20Jakob%20Christensen-Dalsgaard%20(SDU),%20Coen%20P.H.%20Elemans%20(SDU),%20Hannah%20ter%20Hofstede%20(Darthmouth,%20USA),%20Lasse%20Jakobsen%20(SDU),%20Mark%20Johnson%20(Aarhus%20University,%20DK),%20Elodie%20Mande-Briefer%20(Copenhagen%20University,%20DK),%20Natasha%20Mhatre%20(University%20of%20Western%20Ontario,%20CN),%20Ole%20N%C3%A6sbye%20Larsen%20(SDU),%20Peter%20Teglberg%20Madsen%20(Aarhus%20University,%20DK),%20Nicolas%20Mathevon%20(ENES,%20FR),%20Jeppe%20Have%20Rasmussen%20(Copenhagen%20University,%20DK),%20Jakob%20Tougaard%20(Aarhus%20University,%20DK),%20Magnus%20Wahlberg%20(SDU),%20Sue%20Anne%20Zollinger%20(Manchester%20Metropolitan%20University,%20UK).%20%20%20The%20course%20is%20taught%20at%20the%20marine%20and%20terrestrial%20field%20stations%20of%20the%20Department%20of%20Biology,%20University%20of%20Southern%20Denmark.%20%20%20Application%20should%20be%20emailed%20to%20bioacoustics@biology.sdu.dk%20%20%20%20Application%20deadline:%20April%201st,%202024.%20%20Priority%20is%20given%20to%20students%20enrolled%20in%20a%20PhD-program%20at%20their%20home%20universities.%20Maximal%20number%20of%20participants:%20%2024.%20Successful%20applicants%20will%20be%20notified%20of%20acceptance%20before%20May%201st,%202024.%20%20%20More%20information%20and%20application%20requirements:%20https://www.sdu.dk/en/forskning/sound-communication-behaviour/education/graduate-course-bioacoustics)

Comment: I'm surprised to see this downvoted. Yes, it is an advertisement masquerading as a question. But on the flip-side, it is also on-topic and well targeted.

Comment: I'm not surprised as this happend before. However this announcement, slightly modified, would IMHO be an appropriate answer for the hihgly voted https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/121/holistic-intro-to-bioacoustics-for-newbies